# shared_ptr<int[]> doesn't compile

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
int main()
{
    //instruction 1 -> OK
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> sp2(new int[10]);

    //instruction 2 ->error does not compile
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> sp1(new int[10]);
}
```

I was reading about delete and delete[] when memory allocated for smart pointers is with new[]. Why instruction 1 with `std::unique_ptr` is ok and with `std::shared_ptr` isn't ?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  GCC 8 for example rejects the one your compiler accepts and vice versa.

Comment: http://cpp.sh c++14

Comment: Gcc (trunk) and clang (trunk) both compile with no issues.

Comment: cpp.sh is using incomplete 4.9 build which did not had complete C++11/C++14 support

Answer (score 1):

GCC 7 or later will compile the code you're having problems with: https://godbolt.org/z/pTWWVG

The "cpp.sh" website you linked in a comment uses GCC 4.9 which is pretty old, and was the first version that claimed to support C++14.

Comment: it didn't claim it, it claimed to support some features, there is table on gcc site which lists supported features. Neither C++11 nor C++14 were supported fully until 7.0. This property of smart pointers was a backport from C++17, I think.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: It's true that some parts of C++14 were missing in GCC 4.9, but I can't find any reference that agrees with your claim that "Neither C++11 nor C++14 were supported fully until 7.0".  See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html and here: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14 which make it clear that GCC 5 added some missing C++14 features.